# CDI injection always null

Tags: cdi, javabeans, payara, java-ee-8

Hi I'm trying to Inject an object in my code. But for some reason it will keep null.

The following things I tried; 
Adding a PostConstruct(which isn't called...) 
Removing other parts of CDI to just get the first Injection working. 
Also checked if CDI is enabled in Payara.

I added an beans.xml to meta-inf & web-inf

Shortend version of the code where I call the bean.

```
public class MovieFacade implements iMovieFacade {
    @Inject
    private iMovieDao md;
    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        System.out.println(md);//I do this to test if the postConstruct is called
    }   
    public List<Movie> getAllMovie() {
        return md.getAllMovies();
    }
}
```

Shortend code of the class I try to call.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MovieDao implements iMovieDao {

private DataStoreMaker dataStoreMaker;
private DCM dcm;

    @PostConstruct
    private void onInit(){
        dataStoreMaker = new DataStoreMaker();
        dcm = new DCM(dataStoreMaker.movieDS());
    }
    public List<Movie> getAllMovies(){
        List<Movie> ml = dcm.find().asList();
        return ml;
    }
}
```

The interface

```
public interface iMovieDao {
    void newMovie(Movie movie);
    Movie getId(String id);
    List<Movie> getAllMovies();
    void editMovie(Movie movie);
}
```

Comment: Have you put Stateless on MovieFacade ? ApplicationScoped is for the whole app so the  PostConstruct will be called in the beginning.

Comment: How are you calling the `MovieFacade`? How are you obtaining a reference to it?

Comment: Are you correctly using the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation from the `javax.enterprise.context` package ? It sounds like you might be using the JSF-specific one.

Answer (score 0):

In Java EE your MovieFacade should be a bean to be managed by container (have lifecycle).
To do this just add annotation of your choice, for example @Stateless.

```
@Stateless
public class MovieFacade implements iMovieFacade {
    @Inject
    private iMovieDao md;
    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        System.out.println(md);//I do this to test if the postConstruct is called
    }   
    public List<Movie> getAllMovie() {
        return md.getAllMovies();
    }
}
```